# How can i set an ENV variable in a Dockerfile the content from a .txt file?

Tags: node.js, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

I'm trying to Dockerize a Node.js app and, while creating the Dockerfile, i came across the problem that the credetials for connecting to the database are stored in a .txt file. How can i set the content from that .txt file as an ENV variable in my Dockerfile?

Comment: write a shell script that extracts those credentials and writes some lines in the Dockerfile such as `ENV mypassword abc123`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `--env-file` command line option:

```
docker run --env-file ./env.list ubuntu bash
```

> This file should use the syntax `<variable>=value` (which sets the
>   variable to the given value) or `<variable>` (which takes the value from
>   the local environment), and `#` for comments.

For more details, [see the documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e-env-env-file).